# How to validate a form when not scrolled down using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am trying to validate a form for a page called 'Agree to information'. Here, the user has to scroll down in order to move forward(remember no checkbox at bottom of the box, instead user has to scroll down all the way till the scroll ends), if the user clicks the continue/agree button without scrolling, a div element/error must be displayed saying 'Scrolling to the bottom of the information is required'(must be a anchor link, clicking on it should highlight the box with color). here is the code and image

```
 (function(){
    angular
        .module('agreeToInfoApp',[])
        .directive('execOnScrollOnBottom', [function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                    var fn=scope.$eval(attrs.execOnScrollOnBottom),
                        clientHeight=elem[0].clientHeight;
                    elem.on('scroll',function(e){
                        var el=e.target;
                        if ((el.scrollHeight-el.scrollTop) === clientHeight) {
                            elem.addClass('class-summary')
                            scope.$apply(fn);
                        };
                    });
                }
            };
        }]);
})();
```

html:

```
<body>
<div class="class-summary">
    <div class="open">
        <p>Some Information Missing</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Please scroll down to lookup the information</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<form name="myform" >
    <div cols="3" exec-on-scroll-on-bottom name="agreeTerms" class="agree-terms" >
        <p>adsfadfad</p>
        <p>adsfadfad</p>
        <p>adsfadfad</p>
        <p>adsfadfad</p>
        <p>adsfadfad</p>
        <p>adsfadfad</p>
        <p>adsfadfad</p>
        <p>adsfadfad</p>
        <p>adsfadfad</p>
        <p>adsfadfad</p>
        <p>adsfadfad</p>
        <p>adsfadfad</p>
    </div><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Continue" >
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../lib/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

Please let me know what i am missing here or is there any other way?

[Agree To Information Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcWtA.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your condition just needs a little tweaking and it's good to go.

```
if (el.scrollTop === el.scrollHeight - el.offsetHeight) {
  // scrolled to bottom
}
```

**JSFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/030d6pb0/**